Updating data in TestFlight is not working
I am doing an app in flutter and the business user has the option to edit their data that they fetch in firestore when they created an account. In simulator everything works fine , only in test flight this functionality is not working anymore and I can't tell why. Here is the code for it and let me know how I can detect and issue because app is not crashing or anything when I try to do this
void _saveChanges() async {
  try {
    // Show loading indicator
    if (mounted) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      );
    }

    // Create business hours data map
    final businessHoursData = {
      'timeOpen': openTimeController.text.trim(),
      'timeClosed': closeTimeController.text.trim(),
      'workingDays': workingDaysController.text.trim(),
      // Include these for backward compatibility
      'openTime': openTimeController.text.trim(),
      'closeTime': closeTimeController.text.trim(),
      'workDays': workingDaysController.text.trim(),
      'lastUpdated': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), // Add timestamp for tracking
    };

    print('Attempting to save business hours: $businessHoursData'); // Debug log

    // Update username if provided
    if (_userNameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(userId).update({
        'name': _userNameController.text.trim(),
      });
      print('Username updated successfully'); // Debug log
    }

    // Update business hours in both locations
    await Future.wait([
      // Update in BusinessAccount/detail
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(userId)
          .collection('BusinessAccount')
          .doc('detail')
          .set(businessHoursData, SetOptions(merge: true)),
      
      // Update in main Users document
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(userId)
          .update(businessHoursData),
    ]);

    print('Business hours updated successfully'); // Debug log

    // Close loading indicator
    if (mounted && Navigator.canPop(context)) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    // Refresh data
    await getData();
    await fetchScheduleData();

    // Show success message
    if (mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Changes saved successfully'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ),
      );
    }
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    // Log the error and stack trace
    print('Error saving changes: $e');
    print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');

    // Close loading indicator if it's showing
    if (mounted && Navigator.canPop(context)) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    // Show error message
    if (mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error saving changes: ${e.toString()}'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
Future<void> fetchScheduleData() async {
  try {
    // Try to get data from BusinessAccount/detail first
    DocumentSnapshot scheduleDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('BusinessAccount')
        .doc('detail')
        .get();

    // If no data in BusinessAccount/detail, try main Users document
    if (!scheduleDoc.exists) {
      scheduleDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(userId)
          .get();
    }

    if (scheduleDoc.exists) {
      setState(() {
        scheduleData = scheduleDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;
        // Update controllers with the latest data
        openTimeController.text = scheduleData?['timeOpen'] ?? 
                                scheduleData?['openTime'] ?? '';
        closeTimeController.text = scheduleData?['timeClosed'] ?? 
                                 scheduleData?['closeTime'] ?? '';
        workingDaysController.text = scheduleData?['workingDays'] ?? 
                                   scheduleData?['workDays'] ?? '';
      });
      print('Fetched schedule data: $scheduleData'); // Debug print
    } else {
      print('No schedule data found');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching schedule data: $e');
  }
}`

